# Intra day data with TradingChart

Tags: plotting, charts, finance

I am trying to use `TradingChart` to display some intra day data (60 s. resolution). Is there a way to modify the time displayed when moving the mouse over the data. The default setting (see top left of the chart) is to show `O,H,L,C` and the date **without** the hours, minutes and seconds. Is there a way to modify this display to include hours, minutes and seconds ?
Explicitly, consider the following code:

```
data = {{{2015, 6, 15, 10, 51, 0.`}, {53.19`, 53.19`, 53.19`, 53.19`, 
100}}, {{2015, 6, 15, 12, 19, 0.`}, {53.3`, 53.33`, 53.3`, 53.32`,
 1200}}, {{2015, 6, 15, 13, 49, 0.`}, {53.22`, 53.24`, 53.2`, 
53.2`, 3800}}, {{2015, 6, 15, 15, 14, 0.`}, {53.395`, 53.41`, 
53.395`, 53.405`, 3500}}, {{2015, 6, 16, 10, 6, 0.`}, {53.08`, 
53.09`, 53.07`, 53.07`, 2000}}, {{2015, 6, 16, 11, 31, 
0.`}, {53.2`, 53.21`, 53.2`, 53.21`, 800}}, {{2015, 6, 16, 13, 5, 
0.`}, {53.24`, 53.26`, 53.24`, 53.26`, 1500}}, {{2015, 6, 16, 14, 
36, 0.`}, {53.26`, 53.27`, 53.26`, 53.27`, 1400}}}
TradingChart[data]
```

The output looks something like:[image]

As you can see at the top of chart, the time displayed is only for the day and does not include the time (hours,min,sec). Is there an easy command which would change this date display to include the time of the day as specified in the data ?

Comment: Please include an example of code and data that represents your problem.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** In version 11.3.0 and  version 12.2.0 the the following replacement rule works:

```
TradingChart[data, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 {Rule[_, _String?Internal`PossibleDateQ] ..} :> 
  MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> DateString[#[[1]]] &, data]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Post-process `TradingChart` output to modify the date legend:

```
TradingChart[data] /. Dispatch[System`TradingChartDump`$visdates]:> 
   Dispatch[MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> DateString[#[[1]]] &, data]]
```

[image]

In version 9, you can use

```
TradingChart[data] /. Dispatch[{(_ -> _String) ..}, ___] :> 
   Dispatch[MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> DateString[#[[1]]] &, data]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So I just checked your code and can't reproduce the same behavior. What is your Mathematica version ?

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce, i am using version 9.

Comment: So for version 11, your code doesn't change the output I showed in my question.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce, can you check if  ``TradingChart[data] /.  Dispatch[System`TradingChartDump`$visdates]:>   Dispatch[MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> DateString[#[[1]]] &, data]]`` works in version 11?

Comment: Great it worked ! If you want to add it to your answer above, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is not possible. But you can use tooltips on the chart:

```
TradingChart[Tooltip[#, DateString@#[[1]]] & /@ data]
```

I hope it will still be helpful to you.