# InteractiveTradingChart with date and time displayed for selected data

Tags: plotting, charts, finance, interactive

It is possible to modify `TradingChart` such that instead of just the date, [date and time are displayed for a selected data point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/intra-day-data-with-tradingchart/86075#160629). Is there a "trick" that works as well for `InteractiveTradingChart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{{2015, 6, 15, 10, 51, 0.}, {53.19, 53.19, 53.19, 53.19, 100}}, 
  {{2015, 6, 15, 12, 19, 0.}, {53.3, 53.33, 53.3, 53.32, 1200}}, 
  {{2015, 6, 15, 13, 49, 0.}, {53.22, 53.24, 53.2, 53.2, 3800}},
  {{2015, 6, 15, 15, 14, 0.}, {53.395, 53.41, 53.395, 53.405, 3500}},
  {{2015, 6, 16, 10, 6, 0.}, {53.08, 53.09, 53.07, 53.07, 2000}}, 
  {{2015, 6, 16, 11, 31, 0.}, {53.2, 53.21, 53.2, 53.21, 800}}, 
  {{2015, 6, 16, 13, 5, 0.}, {53.24, 53.26, 53.24, 53.26, 1500}},
  {{2015, 6, 16, 14, 36, 0.}, {53.26, 53.27, 53.26, 53.27, 1400}}};

itc = InteractiveTradingChart[data]
```

[image]

We can post-process `itc` to replace the default date string with one that includes `"Hour"` and `"Minute"`:

```
Replace[First @ itc, HoldPattern @ DateString[a_, _] :> DateString[a,
  {"DayNameShort", ". ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year", 
    " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}], All]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting to see how `FullForm[itc]` differs from `FullForm[First@itc]` in the sense that the latter reveals more about the internal structure.

Comment: Just a minor remark: `ImageSize -> Large` does not have any effect, i.e., `ImageSize -> Small` or having no `ImageSize` option set instead results in the same image size. However, setting `ImageSize` to a specific value does work. This is of course completely irrelevant for the actual question.

Comment: Another very minor comment is that `HoldPattern@DateString[a_, _] :> ...` avoids the use of `Quiet`.

Comment: @MathGaudium, I updated with the cleaner version per your comments. Thank you for the accept.